# Run another function when an annotated method is called

Tags: java, spring, annotations

Is there a way to create a custom, or use an existing, annotation to trigger code to run when the annotated method is called? Preferably, I would like to use Spring libraries.

For example:

```
@SendEmail("templateName")
public void doSomething() {
    log.info("Something is happening");
}

public void sendEmail(String templateName) {
    // This method is called everytime doSomething() is called
    log.info("Sending email using template " + templateName);
}
```

Comment: Why not just call `sendEmail` from inside `doSomething` ?

Comment: `sendMail` would be used by multiple methods in various classes in the system with different templates. My thinking behind this is that I would be able to avoid declaring/autowiring `sendMails`'s class in each of these classes, to prevent clutter or references to static methods

Comment: Well the only thing I can think of is interseptors, but I don't know if that will work.

Comment: That helped get me in the right direction, thanks! Looking into inteceptors let me to Spring AOP and this [blog post](http://blog.javaforge.net/post/76125490725/spring-aop-method-interceptor-annotation), which seems to be what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class Mail {
    @After("execution (@com.yourdirectoryofyourcustomAnnotation.SendMail * *(..))")
    public void sendEmail(JointPoint jp){
        // it will send a mail after every method which tagged by your annotation
    }
}
```

Comment: It works for me! 
For other users read the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html