# Is there a way to monitor methods so that another method is executed elsewhere in the code?

Tags: java, design-patterns, observable, propertychangelistener

Can someone help me and explain how best to observe a method. This means that when a certain method is executed, the entire system should be recalculated internally at another point, for example. The same for example when a file is uploaded, then certain calculations should be triggered in the background.

Observer is deprecated and PropertyChangeListener does not help me in my case i think.

Does anyone have an idea or pattern how to map this case in Java?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at AspectJ

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there are 2 ways to do it:

1. User AspectJ. Like these two exemples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49159666/how-to-intercept-each-method-call-within-given-method-using-spring-aop-or-aspect), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025674/run-another-function-when-an-annotated-method-is-called)
2. Create you own Annotation. Then you can receive the methods you want to trigger as the parameters. Something like this:

   ```
    @MyCustomTriggerAnnotation(methodsToBeTriggered= {methodA, methodB})
    public void test(){

    }
   ```